# nested joins statement in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

In my rails appI have four models( say A, B, C, D, E and F)

- A belongs to B
- B has many Cs
- C belongs to D
- D belongs to E and F

I am trying to build query as follows

```
scope = A.joins(:b, { b: [:cs, {cs: [:d, {d: [:e,:f] } ] } ] })
```

But it is not working. The error message is `schema cs (plural of c) does not exist`.

I am using `Postgresql`.

Comment: dont forget: `joins(:c)` then `joins(:d)`

Comment: could you show the resulted query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like you're missing a `B` reference (`b_id`) in the C model. `C` needs to know to which `B` it belongs. After that, you can simplify the query to this:

```
A.joins(b: {cs: {d: [:e, :f]}})
```

Comment: I have the reference(without it the app wouldn't work properly). But thanks for the shorter form, though I still have the same error message

Comment: That's weird. It works for me https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a91183837d10ecbb7bf

Comment: The error is on the where clause.                                       scope.where("lower(c.d.description) like ?", "%#{params[:description]}%")

Comment: Try `scope.where("lower(ds.description) like ?", "%#{params[:description]}%")`